# flink kafka source commit offset to error offset, suddenly increase or decrease, is it a bug of flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

- Environment: flink 1.13.6 on yarn
- Application: flink api stream application, consume one topic named 'a' with group.id 'g', with checkpoint, auto commit offset is closed, offset committment is triggered by checkpoint. checkpoint every minutes at 24 second, such as 12:00:24, 12:01:24...
- Problem Description:
  The offset commited to kafka is suddenly increase from a small value (we had a big lag) to a value close to the partioin log offset (infer to nearly no lag at all), and vice versa.
  For better illustration, the following is two pictures of offset monitoring to describe the wierd error.
  [image]
  [image]
  For more detail, I seek to the offset topic to get the commit detail, find that the topic is operation nomally and the offset commited is wierd. (so it's not the problem of kafka).
  [image]
  [image]
  As I mentioned, I check the status of the topic and seek to offset topic find the commited messages, make sure it is the problem of the client side. Is it a bug of flink kafka source or checkpoint?

My assumption is that, the consumer is too slow to catch up with the speed of producer, then old log is delete, the low watermark is higher than the commit offset, so when fetch records, it will throw exception, and according to auto.offset.reset , the default value is latest, then the gap happens, Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Flink commits its offset to Kafka only when a checkpoint has been completed. Flink doesn't rely on the committed offsets for fault tolerance, but only does this for exposing the progress of the consumer and the consumer group for monitoring. This is also documented at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#consumer-offset-committing

Comment: Yes it is. Kafka source commits the current consuming offset when checkpoints are completed, for ensuring the consistency between Flink’s checkpoint state and committed offsets on Kafka brokers. However the question is the wrong offset is being committed by flink after a checkpoint completed. It is too big or too small, not the right offset of the last consumed batch. I am asking why it is wrong. For monitoring, it should commit the right offset, right? It may cause data lost if the offset stored by the checkpoint is wrong too.

Comment: Consuming the data up to the offsets recorded in the checkpoint produces the rest of the state recorded in the checkpoint. That way, the checkpoint is entirely self-consistent, and data loss is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we finally find the answer. After doing more tests, we find out that, it's not the bug of flink, it's a agreed-upon strategy. As far as we know, the topic delete policy will cause some oldest log segments to be deleted. When a consumer is too slow to catch up the speed of the producers, the record fetcher thread will throw OffsetOutOfRangeException, Which is caught by flink kafka consumer, and it will seek to offset recording to the config "auto.offset.reset", this cause the wierd behavoir as I said above, the big slope of the monitoring chat, and it cause data lost.